# Different aggregate functions under one GROUP BY statement

Tags: sql, join, group-by, aggregate-functions

I have following tables:

### Topics:

topicID(PK),
userID(FK),
title,
dateCreated

### Messages:

messageID(PK),
topicID(FK),
userID(FK),
messageBody,
dateCreated

### Users:

userID(PK),
username

---

I want to select a username of the last message, a date when the last message was posted and the number of messages in the topic among other fields.

I was not able to select a username of the last posted message. The best query I came up so far only selects the last date of the last posted message, but not the username. What should I add to my query?

```
SELECT Topics.title, Users.username, Topics.dateCreated, COUNT(Messages.messageID) as postsCount, MAX(Messages.datePosted) as lastPostedDate
    FROM Topics 
    JOIN Users ON Topics.userID = Users.userID 
    JOIN Messages ON Topics.topicID = Messages.topicID 
    GROUP BY Topics.topicID
```

Comment: what dbms are you using? (solution techniques for this differ) looks like MySQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not entirely certain what you are hoping for, but this may help:

```
SELECT
      Topics.title
    , tuser.username            AS TopicUserName
    , MIN(Topics.dateCreated)   AS TopicDate
    , muser.username            AS MessageUserName
    , COUNT(Messages.messageID) AS postsCount
    , MIN(Messages.datePosted)  AS firstPostedDate
    , MAX(Messages.datePosted)  AS lastPostedDate
FROM Messages
      JOIN Users muser
                  ON Messages.userID = Users.userID
      JOIN Topics
                  ON Topics.topicID = Messages.topicID
      JOIN Users tuser
                  ON Topics.userID = Users.userID
GROUP BY
      Topics.title
    , tuser.username
    , muser.username
ORDER BY
      lastPostedDate DESC
LIMIT 0,1
;
```

Comment: This query is only selecting the username who created the Topic. But I need both: the username who created the topic and the username, who posted the last message. Thank you for your time anyway.

Comment: Ha! I found a solution. Will post it soon.

Comment: Oh, ok, I amended my answer anyway

Answer (score 0):

The solution was:

```
SELECT 
Topics.title
, Users.username
, Topics.dateCreated
, COUNT(Messages.messageID) as postsCount
, lastPost.lastPostUser
, lastPost.lastPostDate  
FROM Topics 
JOIN (
    SELECT 
    Max(Messages.datePosted) as lastPostDate
    , Users.username as lastPostUser
    , Users.userID FROM Topics
    JOIN Users ON Topics.userID = Users.userID 
    JOIN Messages ON Topics.topicID = Messages.topicID 
    GROUP BY Topics.topicID) lastPost
ON Topics.userID = lastPost.userID
JOIN Users ON Topics.userID = Users.userID 
JOIN Messages ON Topics.topicID = Messages.topicID 
GROUP BY Topics.topicID;
```

A good way to write such queries is to subdivide it to a several easy queries and merge them at the end. In my case

```
SELECT 
Max(Messages.datePosted) as lastPostDate
, Users.username as lastPostUser
, Users.userID FROM Topics
JOIN Users ON Topics.userID = Users.userID 
JOIN Messages ON Topics.topicID = Messages.topicID 
GROUP BY Topics.topicID;
```

Is just joined to:

```
SELECT 
    Topics.title
    , Users.username
    , Topics.dateCreated
    , COUNT(Messages.messageID) as postsCount
    FROM Topics         
    JOIN Users ON Topics.userID = Users.userID 
    JOIN Messages ON Topics.topicID = Messages.topicID 
    GROUP BY Topics.topicID;
```